# Firebase: Flutter Phone Authentication is Not Working and App Crashes

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use firebase phone authentication but when I press the button to verify number the app crashes and I receive this error:

```
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3cf0e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff50ba89b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3cd4c +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   Runner                              0x000000010e329d01 -[FIRPhoneAuthProvider verifyPhoneNumber:UIDelegate:completion:] + 193
    4   Runner                              0x000000010e8b05e0 -[FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin handleMethodCall:result:] + 17488
    5   Flutter                             0x00000001121c89df __45-[FlutterMethodChannel setMethodCallHandler:]_block_invoke + 104
    6   Flutter                             0x0000000112157622 _ZNK7flutter21PlatformMessageRouter21HandlePlat<…>
Lost connection to device.
```

I enabled the phone authentication method on firebase already abd by the way I use iphone as emulatore and here is my code to verify authentication :

```
Future<void> verifyPhone(phoneNo) async{
final PhoneVerificationCompleted verified = (AuthCredential authResult){
  AuthService().signIn(authResult);
};

final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed = (AuthException authException){
  print('${authException.message}');
};

final PhoneCodeSent smsSent= (String verId, [int forceResend]){
  this.verificationId = verId;
  setState(() {
    this.codeSent = true;
  });
};

final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoTimeout = (String verId) {
  this.verificationId = verId;
};

await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: phoneNo,
    timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
    verificationCompleted: verified,
    verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
    codeSent: smsSent,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoTimeout);
}
```

Comment: check this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16871#issuecomment-383512995

Comment: @griffins I tried it but did not work with me